# Putting the body back through a python milter

Tags: python, email, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

(never mind...solved it)

I've written a milter in Python using pymilter that extracts attachments and saves them to a folder (thanks SO for the recommendation).  I've gotten to the point in writing the milter where I need to put the original body of the message back in with the original formatting, but I'm having difficulty seeing exactly how to do this.

FYI - I am a NOVICE python programmer, but have learned much in the past few days.

Here is my current code for examination:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python
    
    import Milter
    import StringIO
    import email
    import email.Message
    import hashlib
    import mime
    import os
    import sys
    import tempfile
    import time
    import rfc822
    
    from Milter.utils import parse_addr
    
    from email import Errors
    from email.Message import Message
    
    ## ==  IP Information
    from socket import AF_INET, AF_INET6
    ## ==
    
    ## === Define multiprocessing == ##
    
    if True:
        from multiprocessing import Process as Thread, Queue
    else:
        from threading import Thread
        from Queue import Queue
    
    logq = Queue(maxsize=4)
    
    
    def background():
        while True:
            t = logq.get()
            if not t: break
            msg,id,ts = t
            print "%s [%d]" % (time.strftime('%Y%b%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(ts)),id),
            # 2005Oct13 02:34:11 [1] msg1 msg2 msg3 ...
            for i in msg: print i,
            print
    
    ## === End Define Multiprocesing === ##
    
    class mltr_SaveAttachments(Milter.Base):
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.id = Milter.uniqueID()
    
        def close(self):
            # always called, even when abort is called.  Clean up
            # any external resources here.
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        def abort(self):
            # client disconnected prematurely
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        def log(self,*msg):
            logq.put((msg,self.id,time.time()))
        
        @Milter.noreply
        def connect(self, IPname, family, hostaddr):
            self.IP = hostaddr[0]
            self.port = hostaddr[1]
            if family == AF_INET6:
                self.flow = hostaddr[2]
                self.scope = hostaddr[3]
            else:
                self.flow = None
                self.scope = None
            self.IPname = IPname # Name from a reverse IP lookup
            self.H = None
            self.fp = None
            self.receiver = self.getsymval('j')
            self.log("connect from %s at %s" % (IPname, hostaddr) )
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        @Milter.noreply
        def header(self, name, hval):
            self.fp.write("%s: %s\n" % (name,hval)) # add header to buffer
            return Milter.CONTINUE
        
        @Milter.noreply
        def body(self, chunk):
            self.fp.write(chunk)
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        @Milter.noreply
        def eoh(self):
            self.fp.write("\n")             # terminate headers
            return Milter.CONTINUE
        
        def envfrom(self,mailfrom,*str):
        #    self.log("envfrom")
            self.F = mailfrom
            self.R = []
            self.fromparms = Milter.dictfromlist(str)
            self.user = self.getsymval('{auth_authen}')
            self.log("mail from:", mailfrom, *str)
            self.fp = StringIO.StringIO()
            self.canon_from = '@'.join(parse_addr(mailfrom))
            self.fp.write('From %s %s\n' % (self.canon_from,time.ctime()))
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        ##  def envrcpt(self, to, *str):
        @Milter.noreply
        def envrcpt(self, recipient, *str):
            rcptinfo = recipient,Milter.dictfromlist(str)
            self.R.append(rcptinfo)
            
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
    
        def attachment(self):
            msg = self._msg
            attachDir = attach_dir(msg)
            removedParts = []
            payload = []
            
              
            for part in msg.walk():
                fname = ""
                
                self.log(part.getparams())
    
                if part.is_multipart():
                    continue
                
                dtypes = part.get_params(None, 'Content-Disposition')
    
                if not dtypes:
                    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                       payload.append(part)
                       continue
                    ctypes = part.getparams()
                    if not ctypes:
                        continue
                    for key,val in ctypes:
                        if key.lower() == 'name':
                            fname = val
                else:
                    for key,val in dtypes:
                        if key.lower() == 'filename':
                            fname = val
                            
                if fname:
                    removedParts.append(fname)
                    data = part.get_payload(decode=1)
                    extract_attachment(data, attachDir, fname)
                    part = self.delete_attachments(part, fname)
                    payload.append(part)
    
        # del msg["content-type"]
        # del msg["content-disposition"]
        # del msg["content-transfer-encoding"]
    
        # msg.set_payload(payload)
        self._msg = msg

        out = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        try:
            self.log("dumping")
            msg.dump(out)
            out.seek(0)
            msg = rfc822.Message(out)
            msg.rewindbody()
            while 1:
                buf = out.read(8192)
                if len(buf) == 0: break
                self.replacebody(buf)
        finally:
            out.close()

        self._msg.attach(payload)
    
            return Milter.CONTINUE
    
        def delete_attachments(self, part,fname):
            for key,value in part.get_params():
                part.del_param(key)
                
            part.set_payload('[DELETED]\n')
            del part["content-type"]
            del part["content-disposition"]
            del part["content-transfer-encoding"]
            part["Content-Type"] = "text/html, name="+fname+".html"
            return part
    
    
        def eom(self):
            self.fp.seek(0)
            msg = mime.message_from_file(self.fp)
            self._msg = msg
            
            self.attachment()
            
                    
    
    #        self.log("### MESSAGE ###")
    #        self.log(self._msg)
    
    #        return Milter.ACCEPT
            return Milter.TEMPFAIL
    ## ===
    
    
    
    
    
    def attach_dir(msg):
        tempname = fname = tempfile.mktemp(".tmp")
        out = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        msg.dump(out)
        out.seek(0)
        buf = out.read()
        hashDir = hashit(buf)
        attachDir = dropDir + hashDir
        
        if not os.path.isdir(hashDir):
            os.mkdir(attachDir)
    
        return attachDir
    
    
    def extract_attachment(data, attachDir, fname):
        exdir_file = attachDir + "/" + fname
        extracted = open(exdir_file, "wb")
        extracted.write(data)
        extracted.close()
        
    
    
    def hashit(data):
        sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
        sha1.update(data)
           
        return sha1.hexdigest()
    
    dropDir = "/dropdir/"
    
    def main():
        bt = Thread(target=background)
        bt.start()
        socketname = "/tmp/py_testmilter.sock"
        timeout = 600
        Milter.factory = mltr_SaveAttachments
        flags = Milter.CHGBODY + Milter.CHGHDRS + Milter.ADDHDRS
        flags += Milter.ADDRCPT
        flags += Milter.DELRCPT
        Milter.set_flags(flags)     # tell Sendmail/Postfix which features we use
        print "%s milter startup" % time.strftime('%Y%b%d %H:%M:%S')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        Milter.runmilter("py_testmilter",socketname,timeout)
        logq.put(None)
        bt.join()
        print "%s milter shutdown" % time.strftime('%Y%b%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: iirc there is a self.replacebody method you can use to set the new body. I haven't used the library in a while but I beleive there was a sample milter in the root of the package where this is covered

Comment: I've worked with that, but I can't get it to put anything but plain text back.  My HTML tests are failing.  I accidentally removed that bit of code from what I posted.  Edits made above.

Comment: edits not made yet.  system reverted to old code by accident BEFORE I committed it to my GIT repository.

Comment: Just solved this issue - see edited code

Comment: @Larry G. Wapnitsky: I don't see what changed - may be if you added an answer of what you changed to fix your code.

Comment: I think that if you don't form the multipart MIME message correctly, it will appear as text in the received mail.